# Reference HTTP headers in WSDL

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, http-headers

Is there an easy way to retrieve custom HTTP headers by representing them in the WSDL contract?

For example, suppose I am doing a WSDL-first deployment of a web service using Apache CXF, and I know that the website/client that invokes my service will have a custom HTTP header named `customAuthToken` set. Is there an easier way to interpret the headers using the generated java stubs?

I was able to retrieve the headers using CXF interceptors, but it still poses challenges when I have to use the value from `customAuthToken` later in my business layer / implementation flow.